# Can this system be solved algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$6x+zy=57\\
(4+x)(6+y)=81\\
z(6+y)=81$$

Is there a way to solve it algebraically? I already know the answer, I just need to know if it can be solved.

Comment: As opposed to graphically?

Comment: You can start by solving for a single variable, and substitute. For example, $z = 4+x$

Comment: As long as it's mathematical (which matrices are) then go for it. I just want a mathematical method for finding the unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the last two equations, we find that:
\begin{align*}
(x+4)(y+6) = 81 = z(y+6) &\iff (x+4)(y+6) - z(y+6) = 0 \\
&\iff (x+4-z)(y+6) = 0
\end{align*}

Now observe that $y+6 \neq 0$ (otherwise, if $y+6 = 0$, then the last equation would imply that $0 = 81$, a contradiction). So we may safely divide through by $y+6$ to obtain:
$$
x+4-z = 0 \iff \boxed{z=x+4}
$$
Substituting this into the first equation yields:
$$
6x + (x+4)y = 57 \iff \boxed{y = \dfrac{57 - 6x}{x+4}}
$$
Note that we may safely divide through by $x+4$ (otherwise, if $x+4 = 0$, then the last equation would imply that $0 = 81$, a contradiction). Hence, we obtain the following infinite family of solutions:
$$
\begin{cases}
x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{-4\} \\
y = \dfrac{57 - 6x}{x+4} \\
z=x+4
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your time spent solving that. I guess there's no definite answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The second and third equation tell you that $ 4+x = z$.

Substitute this into the first equation, we get $6(z-4) + zy = 57 \Rightarrow z(6+y) = 81$. hence, the first equation is redundant.

They system of solutions would thus be

$ z = z, y = \frac{81}{z} - 6, x = z - 4$.

Comment: Can those be solved using substitution or elimination?